# Redirect user to Login page, from an jquery ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Iam using custom Authorize filter to on my action method to check if user has an access to it.
If user does not have an access then user is redirected to Unauthorize page.

The problem iam facing here is iam using Jquery Ajax request to call that action method. Everything works well if the user has an access. But if the user does not have an access the code is not able to bind the View("Unauthorize") and it display the existing view on the browsers screen;

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that ajax requests can not send a redirect response. You can instead either return a status code that tells the calling javascript to redirect or simply change the `Response.ContentType` to `application/javascript` and use `window.location = "newUri"` as the response body.

Comment: unless I missed something, shakti is describing an Authorize filter that makes an Ajax call for validation. I've never used that kind of custom filter, but I suspect they would be able to redirect like any other Authorization filter.

Comment: @DaveA: Not for ajax requests.

Comment: OIC, yeah the request would be initiated from View. Yes, I stand corrected.

Comment: @jgauffin, i need to use "application/json; charset=utf-8" as content type as i need to post json data to server. This data is capture in an Action Method which has custom Authorise Attibute above it. This attribute is need to check if user has access to that method and if not the user should be redirected to another Action Method which bind another View name as "Unathorize" to the browser. All this works if my request is normally done via a Submit button. But in current case i want to post the data async'ly hence iam using ajax and json. But ajax request is not able to bind another view.

Comment: You have to use a custom authorize attribute which recognizes ajax requests as regular `Response.Redirect()` will not work for them. And that permission denied answer has to return `application/javavascript` to be able to do a redirect